# Source RPM Can't Find Files

Tags: redhat, rpm

I'm trying to build an RPM of a node.js project I'm working on. The project's code is entirely contained in one directory and its subdirectories. Here's part of my build script:

```
Put everything in the SOURCES directory, except the node_modules
echo "Copying sources..."
cd $DIR/dashboard
tar -zcf $DIR/rpmbuild/SOURCES/project-$VERSION.tgz . --exclude=node_modules > /dev/null
cd $DIR

# Create the spec file
touch $DIR/rpmbuild/SPECS/specfile
# write to it
cat >$DIR/rpmbuild/SPECS/specfile <<EOL
Summary: [Summary]
Name: [Name]
Version: $VERSION
Release: 1
License: GPL
Group: Applications/WebApp
Source: [Name]-$VERSION.tgz
Vendor: None
Requires: nodejs

%description
[Description]

%prep
echo "in prep"
echo $(ls -al)
%setup -c
npm install
yes | ./compile_all.sh
mv app/index.html app/index_big.html
mv app/index_small.html app/index.html

%build
echo "Nothing to build!" 

%install
mkdir -p /opt/project
mv -r ./ /opt/project
ln -s /opt/project/server_start /usr/local/bin
ln -s /opt/project/server_stop /usr/local/bin

%files
$DIR/rpmbuild/SOURCES
$DIR/rpmbuild/SPECS

EOL

HOME=`pwd` rpmbuild -bs $DIR/rpmbuild/SPECS/specfile
```

The `compile_all.sh` script just minifies the html, css, and javascript and concatenates them. `index_small.html` uses the smaller versions. $DIR points to the location of the script, which is one directory above the project code.

The script does indeed generate the source rpm. I've looked at it using `mc`, and inside `CONTENTS.cpio` there's the specfile and the tgz archive of the source code. However, trying to install doesn't work. With `rpm -Vp project.rpm`, I can see that it lists the specfile and the tgz archive as `missing`. With verbose mode enabled, I see something similar to:

```
Directories not explicitly included in package: 
    /home/USERNAME/rpmbuild/SPECS/
    /home/USERNAME/rpmbuild/SOURCES`
```

My rpmbuild directory isn't in my home directory, it's in the same directory as the build script. This leads to my actual question: how can I point rpmbuild at the correct location?

Comment: Where do you expect the `%files` section is getting the value of `$DIR` from? Also, SRPM creation is automatic you don't need to do anything to make it happen. That is your `%files` list should be the list of files to include in the output RPM itself. You should also almost certainly be running `compile_all.sh` in `%build` instead of in `%prep` though that likely doesn't much matter in practice.

Comment: $DIR is defined outside of the `cat` command, and is being included correctly in the generated specfile. And you're right, I don't know what I was thinking putting compilation in the prep section.

Comment: Ah, I missed the generation of the spec file. Sorry. What are you trying to include in your output rpm file? The srpm file is, as I said, automatic (and different).

Comment: The source, in a tgz archive (there's nothing to compile because it's a node.js application, so the .js files and the static content it serves are all that's needed to be in the package). My goal was to have the %install section copy that to /opt/project and symlink some shell scripts to /usr/local/bin to start and stop the server.

Comment: Then those are the files that you want to list in the `%files` section. And you want to copy those files to those locations under the buildroot during `%install`. The paths in the `%files` section are implicitly beneath buildroot by default as well, so no need to include the full path information to them.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I fully understand what you mean. I do copy the files in `%install`, and I believe I'm listing the files (the tar archive is created in SOURCES).

Comment: Why are you creating your output tar archive in SOURCES? That's for input sources to the rpm build process. And my point about `%files` is that every entry is implicitly prefixed with `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT` or `%buildroot` before being used. So with `$DIR` on there you get entries of `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT/$DIR/...`.